# When am I doubling my memory usage?

Tags: java, servlets, jvm, jetty

I have a servlet that users post a XML file to.

I read that file using:

```
String xml = request.getParameter("...");
```

Now say that xml document is 10KB, since I created the variable `xml` I am now using 10KB of memory for that variable correct?

Now I need to parse that xml (using xerces), and I converted it to a input stream when passing to it to the saxparsers parse method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html).

So if I convert a string to a stream, is that doubling my memory usage?

Need some clarifications on this.

If I connect my process with visualvm or jconsole, while stepping through the code, can I see if I am using additional memory as I step through the code in my debugger?

I want to make sure I am not doing this inefficienctly as this endpoint will be hit hard.

Comment: If you want to check by yourself what's going on, you are looking for a profiler (YourKit is quite good, although not free)

Comment: You don't really have an alternative if it's a request param.  If you put it in the body of the message you can read the stream directly into an XML structure.

Comment: Using a stream for reading a string does not double the memory - in fact it is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 10,000 bytes of text generally turns into 20 KB.

When you process text you generally need 2-10x more memory as you will be doing something with that information, such as creating a data structure.

This means you could need 200 KB.  However given that in a PC this represents 1 cents worth, I wouldn't worry about it normally. If you have a severely resource limited device, I would consider moving the processing to another device like a server.

Comment: would 1K per second of files change things? :)

Comment: Most mobile phones could handle that easily. I wouldn't expect you to have a problem with less than 10 MB/s. If you have higher volumes of data I wouldn't use XML as it will be spending a lot time just converting the data to binary. With binary format you might handle 100 MB/s to 1 GB/s.

Comment: mobile phone?  This is a service running on a server, end clients sending xml files to the service endpoint , a few thousand per second.

Comment: A few thousand a second isn't that much, unless the files are large e.g. 10 KB+ each.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be optimizing your code before actually seeing it running. The JVM is **very** good and fast to recover unused memory.

But answering your question `String xml = request.getParameter("...");` doesn't double the memory, it just allocates an extra 4 or 8 bytes (depending if the JVM is using compressed pointers) for the pointer.

Parsing the xml is different the SAX parser is very memory efficient, so it won't use too much memory, I think around 20 bytes per Handler plus any instance variables that you have... and obviously any extra objects that you might generate in the handler.

So the code you have looks like it's as memory efficient as it can get (depending of what you have in your handlers, of course).

Unless you're working on embedding that code in a device or running it 100k times a second, I would suggest you not to optimize anything unless you're sure you need to optimize it. The JVM has some crazy advanced logic to optimize code and the garbage collector is very fast to recover short lived objects.

Comment: actually I have to build to a few thousand per second, and the server doesn't have that much RAM on it.  and its always good to learn this now before I have issues.

Answer (score 1):

If users can post massive files back to your servlet, then it is best not to use the getParameter() methods and handle the stream directly - [Apache File Upload Library](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

That way you can use the SAX Parser on the InputStream (and the whole text does not need to be loaded into memory before processing) - as you would have to do with the String based solution.

This approach scales well and requires only a tiny amount of memory per request compared to the String xml = getParameter(...) solution.

Comment: File uploads occur via http post ( http://upload.thinfile.com/docs/post.php ). The advantage of processing potentially large parameters as a stream is that it makes DoS attacks less likely. One large request could take down the server as it has to fit the contents of the string into the VM space, and if too large, the VM will just create an OutOfMemoryError. if this is on a secure network and if you only anticipate XML of less than a megabyte, stick to the getParameter() solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will code like this:

```
saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
```

You first need to create `StringReader` around `xml`. This won't double your memory usage, `StringReader` class merely wraps `xml` variable and return it character by character when requested.

`InputSource` is even thinner - it simply wraps provided `Reader` or `InputStream`. So in short: no, your `String` won't be copied, your implementation is pretty good.

Comment: so if I do it on another line from what I understand it is exaclty the same right? i.e ```InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));```  its all references so I'm assuming so but just checking.

Comment: @user1361315: yes, these are only references, you are not copying anything. The memory usage would be much higher if you were using [tag:dom] parsing. Also e.g. adding or removing even one character from a `String` causes the whole string to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't get 2 copies of the string, doubling your memory.  Other things might double that memory, but the string itself won't be duplicated.
Yes, you should connect visualVm and jconsole to see what happens to memory and thread processing.